# How to do routing without .php extension with nginx and php

Tags: php, docker, nginx, url-rewriting

Before I start, I know there are many solutions in StackOverflow regarding this issue but they are not working for my case.

I set up a docker container running Nginx instance with PHP. When I enter such URL, myapp.com/somefile without .php at the end, it cannot find the file. I need to browse this URL to make it work myapp.com/somefile.php.

Here is my configuration with Dockerfile and Nginx config.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.8-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y nginx

# PHP_CPPFLAGS are used by the docker-php-ext-* scripts
ENV PHP_CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS -std=c++11"

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && apt-get install libicu-dev -y \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && apt-get remove libicu-dev icu-devtools -y
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-opocache-cfg.ini

COPY nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**nginx-site.conf**

```
server {
    root    /var/www/html;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 30m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

**Note**: I tried to add this lines of code to the nginx config but i ended up downloading files instead of executing them :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you cannot force nginx to force serving PHP script via PHP `location` handler with something like `try_files $uri $uri.php ...`. You can try this config instead (yes, I know that some `if` blocks are evil, but don't worry, this one isn't):

```
location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # default PHP handler here
    ...
}

location @extensionless-php {
    if ( -f $document_root$uri.php ) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

If you want to redirect all the not found requests to `index.php`, use this one instead:

```
location @extensionless-php {
    if ( -f $document_root$uri.php ) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is the first time I'm touching PHP. So I don't have any knowledge about it. What should I enter to the # default PHP handler here area?

Comment: @GürkanGüran Did you put all the fastcgi staff (`fastcgi_pass` and other) into the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block?

Comment: With the configuration you suggested, I'm having a problem with query strings. They are not passed to PHP files. Could you help with that please?

Comment: @GürkanGüran I'm sorry for the late answer, finally manage to check this solution about query string. My enviroment is different from yours, I'm using default CentOS nginx distribution, but everything is ok for me, query string passed as expected. My distribution use `fastcgi_params` file for initializing the default FastCGI parameters, line that responsible for query string is `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string`. Yours `fastcgi.conf` should have a similar line. Can you check its contents?