# No php extension and pretty url nginx config alternative

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, nginx-config

I just migrated my code from apache to nginx server.

What would be the alternative nginx config to my apache .htaccess.

What i use are rules for removing .php extension and pretty url rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#for pretty url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979718/how-to-do-routing-without-php-extension-with-nginx-and-php/62979832#62979832) almost answer your question except of your last rewrite rule. I'm not an expert in apache mod_rewrite, can you tell me how an URL like `example.com/some/pretty/url` should be rewrited? As `index.php?url=/some/pretty/url` or as `index.php?url=some/pretty/url`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky hey, it should rewrite to index.php?url=some/pretty/url, no slash

Comment: What if your get a request like `example.com/some/pretty/url?a=b`? Should it be processed as `index.php?url=some/pretty/url` (my current answer does exactly that) or as `index.php?url=some/pretty/url&a=b`?

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, but I was wrong, query arguments should be preserved with that config, request `example.com/some/pretty/url?a=b` would be processed as `index.php?url=some/pretty/url&a=b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
map $uri $pretty_url {
    ~/(.*)$    $1;
}

server {

    ...

    location / {
        index index.php; # replace this to 'index index.php index.html index.htm;' if needed
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # default PHP-FPM handler here
        ...
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        if ( -f $document_root$uri.php ) {
            rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
        }
        rewrite ^ /index.php?url=$pretty_url last;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix by changing one line. There's no need for extra blocks. You just need to change this one line in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site.com.

Change the location / directive try files to:

```
location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```

Hope this works for you too :)